# Why spring-boot jersey with webflux cannot route my request?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Trying to migrate my `jersey-container-netty-http` to `spring-boot`.

I used `JAX-RS` annotations `@GET` `@Path("/test")` routing my request, but it didn't work. I changed the annotations to `@RestController` and `@GetMapping("/test")`, which is part of spring framework, it worked just fine. Any idea?

Demo:
https://github.com/SBZORRO/spring-boot-without-servlet.git

Request `host/test` get a `Whitelabel Error Page`.

```
Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
HTTP GET "/test" 
Mapped to ResourceWebHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/]]
Resource not found
Resolved [ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND] for HTTP GET /test
```

My `spring-boot` code：
This won't work.

```
@Component
public class Test{
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

Tried to add a jersey config, didn't work.

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/restful")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfiguration() {
      register(Test.class);
    }
}
```

This works.

```
@RestController
public class Test{
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

The `jersey-container-netty-http` server code that I need migrate to `spring-boot`:

```
// No @Component here, comparing to `spring-boot` version.
public class Test {
  @GET
  @Path("/test")
  public String test()
  {
    return "good";
  }
}

// Create server
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.packages("packages name");
Channel server = NettyHttpContainerProvider.createServer(uri, resourceConfig, false);
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You need to manually register your rest classes if you want to use jax-rs annotations this is clearly stated in the spring boot docs which i recommend reading before asking on stack overflow https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.jersey

Comment: @Toerktumlare It worked if I use `spring-boot-starter-web` with `spring-boot-starter-jersey`, but it didn't work with `reactor-netty`.

Comment: then please provide a fully working example that proves your point that it "worked with etc etc"

Comment: @Toerktumlare Updated, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I dont see a link to a fully working example, i just see a bunch of random code. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a link to github with an example that proves your statements

Comment: @Toerktumlare Made a demo [https://github.com/SBZORRO/spring-boot-without-servlet.git](https://github.com/SBZORRO/spring-boot-without-servlet.git)